# Cannot start Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

cannot start the Application. Everytime i see this on my console.

> 2019-10-16 16:00:32.557  INFO 3496 --- [  restartedMain]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
>   completed.
>
> 2019-10-16 16:00:32.566  INFO 3496 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

I am not getting any error so far,What i see on console is `Stopping service [Tomcat]` .
I tried so many time even i changed my work directory. But No Luck.
Even i changed the port number but i dont see any progress.can you please help me to figure it out.

My pom.xml  file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.guides.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration-login-springboot-security-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>registration-login-springboot-security-thymeleaf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.5</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> <version>1.7.5</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

.properties file

```
server.port=8083
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard_local?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

logs are below:

```
2019-10-16 16:34:45.368  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.app.dash.DashApplication             : Starting DashApplication on LAPTOP-UH51ORMM with PID 1388 (E:\Download-E\RawTxn\27thSept\Dash\target\classes started by user in E:\Download-E\RawTxn\27thSept\Dash)
2019-10-16 16:34:45.372  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.app.dash.DashApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-16 16:34:45.448  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@37115abe: startup date [Wed Oct 16 16:34:45 SGT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-10-16 16:34:46.993  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$60543c7c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-16 16:34:47.961  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-10-16 16:34:47.999  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-16 16:34:47.999  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2019-10-16 16:34:48.012  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\DATA\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\windows\System32;;.]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.188  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-16 16:34:48.188  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2744 ms
2019-10-16 16:34:48.341  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.342  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.342  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.343  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.343  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.344  INFO 1388 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-10-16 16:34:48.791  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-10-16 16:34:49.321  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-10-16 16:34:49.438  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-16 16:34:49.495  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-10-16 16:34:49.698  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2019-10-16 16:34:49.702  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-10-16 16:34:49.823  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-10-16 16:34:50.101  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2019-10-16 16:34:51.408  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-16 16:34:51.682  WARN 1388 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.dash.service.UsersService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-10-16 16:34:51.683  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-16 16:34:51.685  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-16 16:34:51.699  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-16 16:34:51.705  INFO 1388 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Comment: please post your .property file

Comment: Please post your console log as well

Comment: please show application.properties configuration

Comment: Can you run your maven build in debug: mvn spring-boot:run --debug. 
Post your properties/yml file and debug logs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857478/spring-boot-with-mysql-is-shutting-down-immedietly/51889673

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting

Comment: server.port=8083
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard_local?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

Comment: please provide the full log.

Comment: check @Service Annotation for class UserService

Answer (score 2):

Based on this line of log:

`Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.dash.service.UsersService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

an implementation of UserServive interface is missed.

Answer (score 1):

From the full log:

```
2019-10-16 16:34:51.682  WARN 1388 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.dash.service.UsersService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Looks like there is something wrong with the `UserService`. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Check weather UserServive class has @Service or @Component annotation. 
The @Component annotation marks a java class as a bean so the component-scanning mechanism of spring can pick it up and pull it into the application context. The @Service annotation is also a specialization of the component annotation.